# Very slow writing of a dataframe to file on Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, save, export, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I have a test program that writes a dataframe to file. The dataframe is generated by adding sequential numbers for each row, like

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7.....11
2,3,4,5,6,7,8.....12
......
```

There is 100000 rows in the dataframe, but I don't think it is too big.
When I submit the Spark task, it takes almost 20 minutes to write the dataframe to file on HDFS. I am wondering why it is so slow, and how to improve the performance.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val numCol = 11

val arraydataInt = 1 to 100000 toArray
val arraydata = arraydataInt.map(x => x.toDouble)
val slideddata = arraydata.sliding(numCol).toSeq
val rows = arraydata.sliding(numCol).map { x => Row(x: _*) }
val datasetsize = arraydataInt.size

val myrdd = sc.makeRDD(rows.toSeq, arraydata.size - numCol).persist()

val schemaString = "value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 " +
                   "value6 value7 value8 value9 value10 label"

val schema =
StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, DoubleType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myrdd, schema).cache()

    val splitsH = df.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.1))
val trainsetH = splitsH(0).cache()
val testsetH = splitsH(1).cache()

println("now saving training and test samples into files")

trainsetH.write.save("TrainingSample.parquet")
testsetH.write.save("TestSample.parquet")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn

```
val myrdd = sc.makeRDD(rows.toSeq, arraydata.size - numCol).persist()
```

To

```
val myrdd = sc.makeRDD(rows.toSeq, 100).persist()
```

You've made a rdd with `arraydata.size - numCol` partitions and each partition would lead to a task which takes extra run time. Generally speaking, the number of partitions is a trade-off between the level of parallelism and that extra cost. Try 100 partitions and it should works much better.

BTW, the official [Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism) suggest to set this number 2 or 3 times the number of CPUs in your cluster.

Comment: thanks for the answer! It essentially solved my problem~~~!